# Spaces in Jquery Validation Regex

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

Basically what i am trying to do is validate a form. In one of the fields i want to allow spaces:

I've been using:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "legalname",
    function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9()._-\s]+$/.test(value);
    },
    "Illegal character. Only points, spaces, underscores or dashes are allowed."
);

$("#editform").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            legalname: true
        },
    });
```

This works in Safari, but not in Firefox where it gives me a "invalid range in character class". Any ideas how i can get this working?

Comment: Escape that dash.  Within a character class it defines a character range.

Comment: @RayToal. My thoughts exactly. +1

Comment: You're missing a `}` on the `validate()`, and older versions of IE can flip out over trailing commas like the one below `name:`.

Comment: Or the OP could put the dash at the end.  Interesting about it "working in Safari," eh?

Comment: @RayToal. The suggestion to put the dash at the end is a bit risky. I don't know if the spec specify it's allowed, and anyway it can make problems if someone modify the regex in the future.

Comment: @JaredFarrish its not missing, there just lots of other functions in my script that i didnt need to post here, bad copy and pasting on my behalf there

Comment: @gdoron it's safe to put the dash at the beginning or end of a character class, Sections 15.10.1 and 15.10.2 of the ECMAScript 5 spec  define how it works.  But good point about it being risky in the sense of a possible later modification shifting its position.  Best to explicitly escape the dashes and right brackets at all times, perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try escaping the `-`: As you can see here: **Working demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/svp6D/2

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9()._\-\s]+$/
```

Characters that need to be escaped inside characters class (`[]`) are:

```
- \ / [] ^
```

Comment: <boom> ++1; Yo, can I take initiative and make minor addition to your post plz?

Comment: @Tats_innit. You can do that with asking. I trust you, (And I get notification why my posts were changed so I can review them...)

Comment: I don't know how the rest of you feel, but I find [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) a good resource.

Comment: @gdoron added a working demo of your solution, works like a rocket to mars! `:)`